# Read multiple files in ShinyR and select the required files to read

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I haven't found this question anywhere.
I have to read all the files present in a folder and to display them in Shiny application file upload screen. Here, user will be allowed to select one or more than one files by check-box and those files are to be processed.

Is there any example script of sample script relevant to above posted in github or else where?

Comment: You can list your files with list.files() function.. With a selectInput and a observe function you can read those files. If you are using shiny-server you have to change the file permission to allow shiny to read those files..

Comment: Can you please share an example ?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dummy example (copy / paste and execute):

This example allows a user to read files in a folder and list them in a selectizeInput.. You can read the files and process in the way you desire.. I know there're no checkboxs but you can use other input but selectizeInput (was easier for me).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    selectizeInput(inputId = 'select_input', label = 'Choose your files...', choices = '*', multiple = TRUE),
    verbatimTextOutput('debug')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observe({
        files <- list.files()

        updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = 'select_input', choices = files)
    })

    output$debug <- renderPrint({input$select_input})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```